# How can I use `this=self` for class when callback ES 2016 class definition

Tags: javascript

```
class ForwardHistLumb{
   var self = this;  //I can't declare members here.
   constructor(){ 
    this.self = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: getForwardHistLumbUrl,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: [],
      success: function(data) {
         this.testFunc(); // undefined error
         this.self.testFunc() // same error 
         self.thisFunc(); // of course error
      }
    });
  testFunc(){
      console.log("hello") 
  }
}
```

Before ES2016,
I can declare member variable as `var self = this`,

So I can use self in callback function.

However variable declaration in class is impossible now.

How can I solve??

---

I changed my code using 'bind' according to @Kartik Anand  , however same error????

```
class ForwardHistLumb{
   var self = this;  //I can't declare members here.
   constructor(){ 
    this.testFunc() = this.testFunc.bind(this)
    $.ajax({
      url: getForwardHistLumbUrl,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: [],
      success: function(data) {
        this.testFunc()/////??????
      }
    });
  testFunc(){
      console.log("hello") 
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use arrow functions to achieve the same effect and keep using `this`. Or just bind the function in the constructor itself like: `this.testFunc = this.testFunc.bind(this)`

Comment: I changed the code using bind, but maybe my understanding is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an arrow function in your success callback

```js
class ForwardHistLumb {
  constructor() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://httpbin.org/get',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: [],
      success: data => {
        this.testFunc(data)
      }
    })
  }
  testFunc(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
}
```

Or if you want to preserve the context of the AJAX object, you can save a reference to that class method in your constructor.

```js
class ForwardHistLumb{
   constructor() { 
    const testFunc = this.testFunc

    $.ajax({ 
      url: 'https://httpbin.org/get',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: [],
      success: function() {
        testFunc(this)  
      }
    })
  }
  
  testFunc(data) {
      console.log(data)  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comment. I can use both `const` and `=>` callback. For me former method is familliar though, I want to learn later modern way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Function.prototype.bind` to preserve value of `this` or simply use arrow function because it does not change `this` depending on context

Comment: Bind is quite difficult thought, but it's good idea to me. I am learning this with fat arrow idea `=>`

Answer (score 0):

Using the same principles as you do, this should work:

```
class Testing {
    constructor() {
        var self = this;

        // this represents your ajax callback
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.result()
        }, 1000);
    }

    result() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}

new Testing();
```

However, consider using a "fat arrow" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to maintain the context of `this`

```
class Testing {
    constructor() {
        // cleaner approach keeping your constructor less poluted
        this.asyncFn();
    }

    asyncFn() {
        // this represents your ajax callback
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.result()
        }, 1000);
    }

    result() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}

new Testing()
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. `=>` is new to me. It's good chance to learn this. And `self` is very familiar to me and easy.

Answer (score -1):

```
class ForwardHistLumb {
    constructor() {
        const self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: getForwardHistLumbUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: [],
            success: function(data) {
                self.testFunc();
            }
        });
    }
    testFunc() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class does not extend another object, thus calling `super()` in your constructor will cast an error. `Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here`

Comment: @entiendoNull  I am sorry, I have written too many react class^ ^